# Spring annotations such as @WithUserDetails and @WithMockUser doesn't seem to work with Spring Boot?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to mock user for unit test in spring boot application. but i failed to use @WithMockUser in my tests.
How to use @WithMockUser in spring boot 1.4.4 release

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/batchUpdateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST})   
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('Users-EDIT_ANY', '') or hasPermission('Users-EDIT_MY', #user)")
    public ResponseWrapper updateUser(@RequestBody UserWrapper user) {
        logger.trace(">> batch update casat users");
        return ;

    }
```

my test

```
@Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    @WithMockUser(username="admin",roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
    public void updateUser() throws Exception{
```

I'm Using spring boot 1.4.4.RELEASE

Comment: could you add the relevant part of the code to the question?

Comment: Like for example if you're using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` as per [the setup section described in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-setup).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How do you retrieve the mocked info in your test?